# Is there a way to add tags programmatically to TFS Work Items?

Tags: vb.net, tfs, tfs-sdk

I want to be able to mass update work items with a certain tag programmatically. Is there currently a way to do this? I've checked the workitem class and have seen that there is a tags property that is readonly. Is there another way to accomplish this through code?

Best,

Michael

Comment: Just a side note, but mass updates can also be done through Excel. If that's an option it's really easy to do

Comment: Are you using TFS 2012? I don't think there is an API or other easy/supported way to update tags using code in that version of TFS. 

Starting with TFS 2013.2 Tags property becomes writable so you can easily update work items using TFS object model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing of Tags through the API and Excel is supported as of 2013.2. I would recommend that you update to the latest version of TFS to get that and tones of other fixes.

As [mentioned by Brian Harry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/02/05/vs-tfs-2013-2-update-2-ctp-released.aspx):

> ### Work Item Tagging
>
> In TFS 2012.2, we introduced lightweight work item tagging to easily categorize and find work items.  We’ve generally gotten good feedback on the feature but plenty of requests for enhancements.  Here’s some things we are adding in this release (*thus 2013.2*):
>
> - ...
> - Object model & REST API support – We added support to access/set tags in the object model and also exposed REST APIs.
> - ...