# Updating Tags on Work Items in TFS 2013 using API?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I have some code where I try to set some tags on some work items using the TFS API:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, WorkItem> kvp in dict)
        {
            kvp.Value.Tags = "test";
        }
```

But when I run the above I get:

```
{"TF26194: The value for the field 'Tags' cannot be changed. "}
```

But maybe they are readonly?

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3933921-allow-editing-work-item-tags-in-visual-studio

Or do I need to ugrade my server to use 2013 update 2:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/02/05/vs-tfs-2013-2-update-2-ctp-released.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add tags programmatically to TFS Work Items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912054/is-there-a-way-to-add-tags-programmatically-to-tfs-work-items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to edit Tags in the API you need at least TFS 2013 Update 2.